# Google Drive API returning 403 userRateLimitExceeded while uploading files asynchronously using aiogoogle

Tags: python, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

So I'm using a third-party python module(not by Google) called [`aiogoogle`](https://aiogoogle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to upload images to google drive asynchronously. It uses python's asyncio, aiohttp to send requests really fast compared to the `gooogleapiclient`. Here is my code:

```
import asyncio, aiohttp, datetime
from aiogoogle import Aiogoogle

class GoogleDriveUploaderAsync:

    def __init__(self):
        # read_json reads the given file and returns a dict
        self._CREDS_FILE = read_json("./credentials.json")
        
        # I'm using a google drive folder's id to use it as a main root folder
        self._MAIN_FOLDER_ID = self._CREDS_FILE["main_folder_id"]
        self._CREDS = self._CREDS_FILE["creds"]
        self._service = None
        
        # using folder 
        self._folder_state = {}
        
        # using a single Aiogoogle object for all uploads
        self._aiogoogle = Aiogoogle(service_account_creds=self._CREDS)
        self._folder_lock = asyncio.Lock()
    
    async def _build_service(self):
        try:
            self._service = await self._aiogoogle.discover('drive', 'v3')
        except Exception:
            print("An error occurred while building the Google Drive service:")
    
    async def upload_file(self, file: bytes, file_name:str, mimetype:str, folder_id:str):
        if self._service is None:
            await self._build_service()

        try:
            
            if folder_id:
                parent_id = folder_id
            else:
                parent_id = self._MAIN_FOLDER_ID
            
            file_metadata = {
                "name": file_name,
                "parents": [parent_id],
            }
            
            
            # creating a Google Drive create request
            upload_req = self._service.files.create(json=file_metadata,upload_file=file, fields="id")
            upload_req.upload_file_content_type = mimetype

            # executing the request asynchronously 
            media = await self._aiogoogle.as_service_account(
                upload_req
            )
            file_id = media.get("id")
            file_link = f"https://drive.google.com/file/d/{file_id}"
            print(f"File link: {file_link}")
            return file_link
        except Exception:
            print("An error occured while uploading the file.")


    async def create_folder(self, folder_name, parent_folder_id=""):

        if self._service is None:
            await self._build_service()
        
        #Used lock because I need to give access to only one request at a time
        async with self._folder_lock:  # Acquire the lock

            # taking already created folder from _folder_state to save time
            if folder_name in self._folder_state:
                return self._folder_state[folder_name]
            try:
                if parent_folder_id:
                    pass
                else:
                    parent_folder_id = self._MAIN_FOLDER_ID

                # creating folder create request
                response = await self._aiogoogle.as_service_account(
                self._service.files.list(
                    q=f"name='{folder_name}' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and '{parent_folder_id}' in parents",
                    fields="files(id)",
                ))
                print(response)

                if len(response["files"]) == 0:
                    folder_metadata = {
                        "name": folder_name,
                        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
                        "parents": [parent_folder_id],
                    }
                    
                    folder = await self._aiogoogle.as_service_account(
                        self._service.files
                        .create(json=folder_metadata, fields="id")
                    )
                    print("CREATED A NEW FOLDER= ", folder.get("id"))

                    folder_id = folder.get("id")
                    self._folder_state[folder_name] = folder_id
                else:
                    
                    # storing new folder_id in _folder_state for future use
                    folder_id = response["files"][0]["id"]
                    self._folder_state[folder_name] = folder_id

                return folder_id
            except Exception:
                print("An error occurred while creating the folder.")


    async def download_image(self, url: str, session: aiohttp.ClientSession):
        if not is_url(url):
            return None
        try:

            VALID_MIME_TYPES = {
                "image/jpeg": ".jpeg",
                "image/png": ".png",
                "image/jpg": ".jpg",
                "image/gif": ".gif",
                "image/tiff": ".tiff",
                "image/webp": ".webp",
                "image/apng": ".apng",
                "image/svg+xml": ".svg",
                "application/octet-stream": get_file_extension_from_url(url=url),
                # get_file_extension_from_url used to get image's type from the URL

            }
            url = yarl.URL(url, encoded=True)
            res = await session.request(method="GET", url=url)
            print(url, res.status)

            mimetype = res.headers.get("Content-Type").lower()

            if mimetype in VALID_MIME_TYPES:
                file_name = f"cimage{VALID_MIME_TYPES[mimetype]}"
                content = await res.read()
                return content, file_name, mimetype
            else:
                return None
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout error occurred while making the request.")
            return None
        except Exception:
            print(f"An error occurred while downloading the image:")
            return None


    async def download_and_upload_image(self, url: str, **kwargs):
        output = await self.download_image(url, **kwargs)
        if output:
            return output
        else:
            file, file_name, mimetype = output

            today = datetime.today()
            
            # creates a folder of today's date
            today_folder = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            folder_id = await self.create_folder(folder_name=today_folder)
            
            # creates a folder: Images
            image_folder_id = await self.create_folder(
                folder_name="Images", parent_folder_id=folder_id
            )
            
            # uploades the file, I'm getting 403 Forbidden error in this method 
            image_link = await self.upload_file(
                file=file,
                file_name=file_name,
                mimetype=mimetype,
                folder_id=image_folder_id,
            )
            return file_name, image_link

    
    # I had to create functions for context managers because Aiogoogle is intended to be used as a context manager
    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        await self._aiogoogle.__aexit__(*args)

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self._aiogoogle.__aenter__()
        return self


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    image_url = "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F602272019%2F1430182031443%2F1%2Foriginal.20230920-130504?w=940&auto=format%2Ccompress&q=75&sharp=10&rect=0%2C15%2C1200%2C600&s=13645e838fd09f2552c8f8500410abec"
    image_urls = [image_url] * 100

    async def main():
    
        async with GoogleDriveUploaderAsync() as uploader:
            # session timeout of 14400 secs
            timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=14400)
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True,timeout=timeout) as session:
                tasks = []

                for url in image_urls:
                    # Create a task for downloading and uploading each image
                    task = asyncio.create_task(
                        uploader.download_and_upload_image(url=url, session=session)
                    )
                    tasks.append(task)

                await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    asyncio.run(main())
```

This code 1) downloads file from URL 2) creates required folders and 3) uploads file, All 3 are performed asynchronously.

I'm getting error `403 userRateLimitExceeded` getting in 3rd step when multiple requests are send to google drive API. **I'm using a service account credentials.** Google drive has a lot higher limit then I'm using[(12000 per minute](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/limits)). I'm not not even sending that many requests.

here is the error:

```
ERROR - An error occured while uploading the file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/events-scrap/utils.py", line 581, in upload_file
    media = await self._aiogoogle.as_service_account(
  File "/home/ubuntu/events-scrap/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogoogle/client.py", line 307, in as_service_account
    return await self.send(
  File "/home/ubuntu/events-scrap/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogoogle/client.py", line 411, in send
    return await session.send(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/events-scrap/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogoogle/sessions/aiohttp_session.py", line 188, in send
    results = await schedule_tasks()
  File "/home/ubuntu/events-scrap/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogoogle/sessions/aiohttp_session.py", line 180, in schedule_tasks
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/events-scrap/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogoogle/sessions/aiohttp_session.py", line 165, in get_content
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/events-scrap/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogoogle/sessions/aiohttp_session.py", line 161, in get_response
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/ubuntu/events-scrap/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogoogle/models.py", line 481, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(msg=self.reason, req=self.req, res=self)
aiogoogle.excs.HTTPError: 



Forbidden

Content:
{'code': 403,
 'errors': [{'domain': 'usageLimits',
             'message': 'User rate limit exceeded.',
             'reason': 'userRateLimitExceeded'}],
 'message': 'User rate limit exceeded.'}

Request URL:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=id
```

Here are usage graph of last **6 hours** for better understanding, I'm using only one service account(event-scraper) and nothing else:

[image]I don't understand this **Errors by credential** as I'm only using one service account why this **Unspecified** is showing in the graph and it looks like **Unspecified** is causing all the 403 errors and not the **event-scraper**.[image]

[image]

I don't know the reason for why this error is occuring. This error occurs in initial requests after some requests upload starts working. I don't know the way to solve it whether it is using async or some google drive issue.

I hope I get the solution. Thanks.

This error doesn't occur if I use 10 URLs but it occurs if I use 50 URLs. I'm using this scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` .